# How do I make my vue-unit-test trigger a click event on v-btn in Vuetify?

Tags: jestjs, vuetify.js, vue-test-utils

I am creating some unit test for my component, but the test keeps failing, since the button I'm testing
keeps not getting triggerd by a click-event.

I've used the docs as a foundation for my test: https://vuetifyjs.com/sv-SE/getting-started/unit-testing/

I've also tried some of the suggestions mentioned here: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-trigger-an-onchange-event/11081/4

But it seems like I'm missing something, anyone who can help me out?

My test:

```
test('If you can click on the Test button', () => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(myComponent, {
            localVue,
            vuetify,

        });

        const event = jest.fn();
        const button = wrapper.find({name: 'v-btn'})

        expect(button.exists()).toBe(true) //this works

         wrapper.vm.$on('v-btn:clicked', event)

        expect(event).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0)

         button.trigger('click')

         expect(event).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)

    })
```

myComponent:

```
<template>

<v-btn class="primary-text" @click.native="methodForTesting($event)">Test</v-btn>

<template>

<script>
methods: {

methodForTesting(){
  console.log('button clicked!')
}
</script>
```

Comment: try to call await wrapper.vm.$nextTick() after button.trigger('click')

Comment: @Anatoly I tried your suggestion, but I still got an error saying: "   expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0
" 
:/

Comment: Try button.vm.$on('v-btn:clicked', event) instead of wrapper.vm.$on('v-btn:clicked', event)

Comment: try button.vm.$emit('click') - this github issue has more information on this https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/919

Answer (score 8):

Hope this help, I changed your HTML a bit.

- Firstly, I added a `<div>` and put `<v-btn>` inside it, this is very
  important.
- Secondly, I declared a data prop called `index` which is
  initialized in `1`.
- Thirdly, I used `data-testid="button"` to identify
  it and find it during test.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn data-testid="button" class="primary-text" @click="methodForTesting">Test</v-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      index: 1
    };
  },
  methods: {
    methodForTesting() {
      this.index++;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Now, for the unit test.

The key is to use `vm.$emit('click')` instead of `.trigger('click')` since `v-btn` is a component of Vuetify. If you were using `button` tag, then you can use `.trigger('click')`.
Also, I changed how jest finds this button.

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

// Utilities
import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'

// Components
import Test from '@/views/Test.vue';

// VARIABLES INITIALIZATION //
const vuetify = new Vuetify()
const localVue = createLocalVue()

// TESTING SECTION //
describe('Testing v-btn component', () => {
  it('should trigger methodForTesting', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Test, {
      localVue,
      vuetify,
    })
    const button = wrapper.find('[data-testid="button"]')

    expect(button.exists()).toBe(true)
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.index).toBe(1)
    button.vm.$emit('click')
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.index).toBe(2)
  })
})
```

Now, when you are doing a unit test, you should check inputs and outputs. In this case, your input is the click event and your output, is not your method been called, but the data modified or sent by this method. That's why I declared `index` to see if it changes when you click the button.

Anyway, if you want to check if your method was called, you can use this code instead

```
describe('Testing v-btn component', () => {
  it('should trigger methodForTesting', async () => {
    const methodForTesting = jest.fn()
    const wrapper = mount(Test, {
      localVue,
      vuetify,
      methods: {
        methodForTesting
      }
    })
    const button = wrapper.find('[data-testid="button"]')

    expect(button.exists()).toBe(true)
    expect(methodForTesting).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0)
    button.vm.$emit('click')
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
    expect(methodForTesting).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
})
```

But you will receive the next error:

```
[vue-test-utils]: overwriting methods via the `methods` property is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version. There is no clear migration path for the `methods` property - Vue does not support arbitrarily 
replacement of methods, nor should VTU. To stub a complex method extract it from the component and test it in isolation. Otherwise, the suggestion is to rethink those tests.
```

This is my first post btw